DBT post_hook macro with arguments in properties.yml
This is a question about dbt + jinja syntax in macro calls and defining this in a schema.yml/properties.yml model file.
I have a working macro definition and inline post-hook config in a model. It applies dbt tags to materialized models in the db (databricks in this case but not important.) It successfully works as an inline config block, when I run the model the table gets tagged in databricks. However, this is failing when I instead define the post-hook in the .yml file.
Here is the macro:
{% macro apply_dbt_tags(relation, tag_list) -%}

    ALTER TABLE {{ relation }} SET TAGS (
        {% for tag in tag_list -%}
            '{{ tag }}' {%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif -%}
        {%- endfor %}
    )

{%- endmacro -%}

Here is the model file (this inline config block works correctly):
-- demo_apply_tags.sql

{{
  config(
    post_hook = "{{ apply_dbt_tags(this, model.config.tags) }}"
    )
}}
select
    'hello there' col1
    , 'general kenobi' col2

The model properties file:
version: 2

models:
  - name: demo_apply_tags
    description: "attempt to apply the tags of this model to the dbx table"
    config:
      tags: ["obi", "wan"]

So I run it,
dbt run --model demo_apply_tags

# now I go to the cloud db console and see the tags are attached to the new table.

I want to move the post_hook definition to the properties file:
models:
  - name: demo_apply_tags
    description: 2nd attempt to apply new tags
    config:
      tags: ["ewoks", "were misused"]
    post_hook: "{{ apply_dbt_tags(this, model.config.tags) }}"

# Compilation Error
#   Could not render {{ apply_dbt_tags(this, model.config.tags) }}: 'model' is undefined


Update 1/n
So going by the documentation in v1.8.5 the above is incorrect as post_hook is a part of the config and should indent one more level in. I also simplified things by refactoring to remove the arguments, as the macro can glean the model and tags from the context (model.config.tags, this):
Exhibit 1A still unsolved
# l ./models/demo/properties.yml

models:
  - name: demo_apply_tags
    description: 2nd attempt to apply the tags of this model to the dbx table
    config:
      tags: ["use", "force"]
      post_hook: "{{ apply_dbt_tags() }}"

$> dbt run --model demo_apply_tags
# Compilation Error
  # Could not render {{ apply_dbt_tags() }}: 'apply_dbt_tags' is undefined

I swear, the above looks to me exactly like the documentation.
FYI simpler 0-arg macro definition:
{% macro apply_dbt_tags() -%}
    {% set tags_list = model.config.tags %}
    ALTER TABLE {{ this }} SET TAGS (
        {% for tag in tags_list -%}
            '{{ tag }}' {%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif -%}
        {%- endfor %}
    )d
{%- endmacro -%}

Working Solution
Anyway, this works at the top level:
# dbt_project.yml
models:
  muh_project:
    demo:
      schema: muh_demo
      materialized: table
      +tags: ['demo', 'kamino']
      +post-hook: "{{ apply_dbt_tags() }}"

The post hook applies those tags to all tables in the models/demo folder, as well as the tags defined in model config in models/demo/properties.yml.
-- databricks SQL
select *
from system.information_schema.table_tags
where catalog_name = 'muh_catalog' and schema_name = 'muh_demo';




catalog_name
schema_name
table_name
tag_name
tag_value




muh_catalog
muh_demo
demo_apply_tags
use



muh_catalog
muh_demo
demo_apply_tags
force



muh_catalog
muh_demo
demo_apply_tags
kamino



muh_catalog
muh_demo
demo_apply_tags
demo




I STILL WANT THE SOLUTION FOR APPLYING MACRO POST HOOK TO CONFIG AT PROPERTIES.YML LEVEL (exhibit 1A), so if anyone can solve this it would be great.

I'm starting to this this might be a yaml formatting question, where my indentation isn't right... omg as inline block, its a component of config. https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/pre-hook-post-hook

This was a bug, first reported in March 2023, related to non late-rendering behavior specifically in properties.yml files. The error message quoted was:
Could not render {{ my_macro() }}: 'my_macro' is undefined

To quote from the problem statement on the merged fix:

Because pre- and post-hooks within properties.yml files are not late-rendered for models, seeds, etc., references to {{ this }}, macros, etc. don't work.

The fix was merged 3 weeks ago and released for dbt-core 1.8.6. Looks like I can upgrade and put this behind me.
